# Finding & correcting missing layer in MXD using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, mxd, update

Am struggling with ArcPy.

Can someone help with a script to identify missing layers (red arrow in TOC) and then to search for the correct file locations & then update the mxd.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  Writing scripts on request is outside the scope of GIS SE, but I'll give an answer that will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Any script to do this will need to start by using [ListBrokenDataSources](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/listbrokendatasources.htm) which:

> Returns a Python list of Layer objects within a map document (.mxd) or
>   layer (.lyr) file that have broken connections to their original
>   source data.

Once you have your script started using the example code at that link, then you will be ready to tackle the remainder.  If you get stuck then ask a new question, showing us your code so far, and any error messages that you are receiving.